# What's the nature of the Night Car side room experiences?

Tags: snowpiercer-2020

In Miss Audrey's Night Car, staff may lead visitors into one of the side rooms. There, visitors are sometimes shown to open up and share traumatizing experiences.

Audrey states that she "made" the Night Car into what it is and that she created this special experience.

On various occasions, it seems the visitors are brought into a trance-like state where they relive some of their memories, and - confusingly - Audrey appears to participate in those memories.

**What is going on there?**

*Note that I'm not referring to the allusions to the Night Car as some sort of a red-light district.*

The way those scenes are presented, they almost look like Audrey could see the visitors' thoughts (either by telepathy or by some technical means), but I kind of rule that out, as the series as a whole does not tend to use those kind of scifi concepts. Or are those scenes just presented in a very "expressionistic" way, while in reality, the visitors just sit down and start talking (maybe slightly helped by some drugs?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During an [interview with Screen Rant](https://screenrant.com/snowpiercer-tv-show-nycc-interview-cast-nightcar/), Lena Hall (the actress who plays Miss Audrey) states that the character is "an incredible empath" with "some psychic abilities":

> **Hall:** Miss Audrey... was supposed to just run this brothel that's on this luxury liner. And then suddenly it's become the ark, so she had to find some other thing that was a little more helpful than just being the madam of a brothel. And **she's an incredible empath, and actually possesses some psychic abilities**, and can help people. she's almost like a therapist, she helps people get off the train in their mind, she helps them deal with the loss of the old world, all of the people they left behind, the death... kind of work through the trauma, so that they can survive in these tight quarters.

[This Tweet](https://twitter.com/SnowpiercerTV/status/1272388028527329280) from SnowpiercerTV also refers to the character as an empath:

> As an empath, Miss Audrey knows everyone's truths. Now is time for them to hear hers.

So, going by this, it would appear that Miss Audrey can literally see and interact with people's memories, rather than those sequences being a visual metaphor.

Comment: Interesting, and (given the way the series presents itself otherwise) indeed quite unexpected to me. As long as we accept the premise of a mostly self-sustaining huge train that can constantly remain in motion over the course of years on a world-spanning track without any maintenance, the only slightly "supernatural" element seen so far was a little bit of cold-resistance-related research by the two scientists on the second train. I'll wait for a few days before I accept this answer.

Comment: Honestly, sobrenatural powers don't really fit the Snowpiercer narrative. Plus, it's kinda weird to think an empath would stay with a monster like Mr Wilford.